# What's the bracket used to fix a kitchen faucet called?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I've got a broken kitchen tap/faucet, and it's because there is a plastic bracket that fits under the sink that has broken.

I need to know the name of it because I can't search for a replacement without knowing the correct search term!

It's got a 30MM hole in it and is otherwise triangular; it fits here (excuse the ascii art!)

```
   //==\\
   ||
   ||
   ||
  +||+      <-- faucet
----------  <-- sink level
  ||||      <-- plastic bracket goes here
  ----      <-- metal plate
```

This is the rough shape;

```
  <-------------------->
    \       ___       /
      \    /   \    /
        \  \___/  /
          \     /
            \_/
```

Comment: Most faucet mounting parts are proprietary to the manufacturer. Have you tried to identify who it is and contacted them?

Comment: Would it like somehow like the white element in the following picture? http://www.zonetravaux.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Changer-mitigeur-cuisine-13.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is from an automotive store but it's the same thing: *retaining washer*.

[image]

([source](http://www.autozone.com/repairguides/Chrysler-Full-Size-Trucks-1989-1996-Repair-Guide/FLUIDS-AND-LUBRICANTS/Front-Wheel-Bearings/_/P-0900c15280070624))

Answer (score 1):

if you cant find it, just find your local maker club and someone there can 3d print or machine it up for you.